# python tornado setup

Tags: python, tornado

I want to use a Python framework that handles sessions (user auth), templating along with MySQL database access (although I can use MySQLdb quite nicely)

Tornado looks promising but, I just can't see how to use it. The sample given has a port listen feature. Does it replace Apache? Exactly how do I configure my server (Centos 5.4) and LAMP setup for this, or is there a better option?

Comment: If somebody gives you a good answer that solves your problem then you should select their answer. This is how you reward the people who are answering your questions.

Comment: What if it doesn't solve my problem? Do people take it personally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Django.

I'm a hardcore Tornado fan but if you need to ask, Django is the best tool for you. Tornado is great but Django is much easier to build when you need a MySQL database thanks to its awesome ORM.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using tornado for production, you can follow their [nginx setup guide](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/overview.html#running-tornado-in-production).

Comment: decided against it but +1 for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

if you using tornado for websockets you can use ha-proxy for proxying socket request to tornado (ngnix not support this)

Answer (score 0):

If you setup tornado via LAMP (apache with mod_wsgi for example) you will lose every single async option in tornado, significant amount of memory and speed.

It's highly recomended to use nginx for serving static files and proxying dynamic requests to the tornado application instance.

Comment: The mod_wsgi module has got nothing to do with using Tornado with Apache as far as using Tornado behind Apache. So not sure why you are even mentioning mod_wsgi.

Comment: Tornado can be instantiated as a wsgi.

Comment: WSGI is a specification and mod_wsgi is an implementation of that specification. You cannot use the words interchangeably. So yes, tornado has a WSGI container for it, but still has got nothing to do with mod_wsgi. The only connection between tornado and Apache is that Apache could be used as a front end to it. Even when you do that, it is untrue that you loose all the async abilities of tornado as tornado as it sits behind Apache can still run in its async mode. The only issue with using Apache as front end is its ability to proxy high number of concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tornado follow nginx.